# discord.js 12 any way to send data from json file to channel?

Tags: json, discord.js, fs

I have json file, that contains info about some players, that looks like this

```json
{
    "208505383361314816": {
        "warns": 8,
        "reason": "test"
    },
    "776387838350196756": {
        "warns": 99,
        "reason": ""
    }
}
```

Then I sort the information by the number of warns. It works perfectly, but i have no idea, how to send a message.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('>topw')) {
        const sorted = [];
        const keys = Object.keys(warns)

        for (let user in warns) {
            const warny = warn[user].warns;

            const entry = {
                [keys[sorted.length]]: warns[user]
            }

            if (sorted.length === 0) {
                sorted.push(entry);

                continue;
            }
            let i = 0;
            while (sorted[i] !== undefined && sorted[i][Object.keys(sorted[i])].warns > warny) {
                i++;
            }

            sorted.splice(i, 0, entry)
        }
        console.log(sorted)

    }
})
```

It should look like a "leaderboard", but with amount of warns

```
e.g: 
name: Bob
warns: 20
reason: test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! :)

### About your JSON file

First of all, quick advice regarding the way you store data: you really, really should store the user info in an array, it would look like that:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "00000000",
        "warns": 10,
        "reason": "test"
    }
]
```

### Getting your data ready

That being said, let's answer your question.
I guess that you'd love to use [`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed)s, take a look at the docs before reading the code, it might help. I will also rewrite a little bit of your code.

#### Reformating it

To make our life easier, we'll reformat the data so we can sort it.

```js
// It's just your JSON file here
const oldWarns = {
  "208505383361314816": {
    "warns": 8,
    "reason": "test"
  },
  "776387838350196756": {
    "warns": 99,
    "reason": ""
  }
}

let newWarns = Object.keys(oldWarns).map((e) => ({
  id: e,
  warns: oldWarns[e].warns,
  reason: oldWarns[e].reason
}))

console.log(newWarns)
```

#### Sorting it

Now that we've got this beautiful array, let's sort it. It's much simpler than you think!

```js
// Precedently generated data
let newWarns = [{
    "id": "208505383361314816",
    "warns": 8,
    "reason": "test"
  },
  {
    "id": "776387838350196756",
    "warns": 99,
    "reason": ""
  }
]

newWarns.sort((a, b) => (a.warns > b.warns ? 1 : -1))
console.log(newWarns)
```

### Sending the data

What you actually asked for.

#### Rendering it with an embed

Alright, everything is set so we can send the data. Here's how to use embeds in Discord.js.

```js
const warnBoard = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Warnboard")
  .setColor("#FF0000")
  .addFields(newWarns.flatMap((e, i) => ( // flatMap will delete all the [] of the array after mapping it
    i >= 25 ? [] : { // the max number of fields in embeds is 25
      name: e.id,
      value: e.warns,
      inline: true // changes the layout
    }
  )))
```

I just used a few of MessageEmbed's features. They can be really nice looking, so feel free to mess around with its props!

#### Making it as simple as it can get

Embeds are too much? You can also just send a string.

````
const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(newWarns, null, 4)
const warnBoard = "```json\n"+ stringifiedData +"\n```"
````

#### Send it

Whether the solution you chose is the string or the embed, this is the way you're gonna send the data.

```js
message.channel.send(warnBoard)
```